# MS Word 2013: How do I change which text boxes are on top of the other?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have two text boxes. One slides under the other so that it is obstructed and covered up. How I do I make one text box have precedence over another? (In terms of depth.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click -> Send to back -> Send backward

You need to right click the side of the textbox and not the text itself.  If the text is selected, you get the text context menu.

Alternatively, you can select the textbox and then click send backward from the drawing tools - format ribbon.